# Include em pasta anterior

Tags: php

Possuo o seguinte include:

```
include('../header.php');
```

nas páginas que estão a mesma pasta que o header o include funciona, porém quando está uma pasta acima não funciona.

> [image: pastas]

A página que possui o include está dentro do *paginas/1998*

os seguintes erros são emitidos:

> Warning: include_once(../acoes/conexao.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../acoes/conexao.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(../acoes/modal.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 6
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../acoes/modal.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 6
>
> Warning: require(../acoes/pagina_verificar.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../acoes/pagina_verificar.php' (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 11

Answer (score 4):

O comando para subir uma pasta é o `../` então caso queira subir mais uma pasta utilize `../../header.php` e assim por diante.

É possível também navegar entre páginas como: `../js/arquivo.js`

Lembre que você tem que fazer esse caminho percorrer a partir de onde está o arquivo que chama o include, se o arquivo estiver na pasta 1998 o correto é `../header.php`. Mas caso o arquivo estiver em acoes, você deve colocar `../paginas/header.php`

Comment: funcionou em partes, mas a página não pegou o CSS e Bootstrap, emitiu os seguintes erros:
Warning: include(../../header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\1998\relatorios_financeiros_98.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening '../../header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\1998\relatorios_financeiros_98.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\1998\relatorios_financeiros_98.php on line 4

Comment: Esse primeiro warning que você apresentou é que agora a página header não está sendo encontrada. Em qual pasta fica o arquivo que chama o seu include?

Comment: ele fica na pasta 1998

Comment: Então o crreto do include é realmente `../header.php`. Esse include não está errado. O problema é em outro local

Comment: tem alguma ideia do que poderia ser?

Comment: pq as páginas que estão na mesma pasta que o header estão funcionando perfeitamente

Comment: Entendi. O problema está no include dentro do header.php, pois quando ele é chamado de dentro de um arquivo dentro da pasta 1998, a chamada `../acoes/conexao.php` na linha 5 do header.php está incorreta partindo da visão de dentro da pasta 1998, precisaria de um `../`a mais

Comment: Para isso, utilize a sugestão do amigo @Valdeir Psr para criar uma constante no seu sistema que te permita sempre saber o caminho do include a partir dele

Answer (score 2):

No `PHP` o caminho dos arquivos é definido tendo como base, o arquivo principal, o `index.php`.

Portanto você deve adicionar os includes como se estivesse no `index.php`.

Estrutura de arquivos:

```
Desktop
│   index.php
│   teste.php
│
└───sd
        teste2.php
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

include "sd/teste2.php";
```

**teste.php**

```
Olá
```

**sd/teste2.php**

```
<?php

include "teste.php";
```

**Dica 1:** Para evitar esse tipo de erro, crie uma constante com o path do `index.php` e utilize ao incluir um arquivo. `define("PATH", __DIR__); include PATH."/acoes/file.php"`

**Dica 2:** Evite a barra no início do caminho, isso significa que você está pegando desde o diretório raiz do servidor.

`/paginas/header.php` = No linux significa que você está pegando o arquivo em `<raiz-do-servidor>/paginas/header.php`

`/paginas/header.php` = No Windows significa que você está pegando o arquivo em `C:\paginas/header.php`

**Dica 3:** Utilize sempre caminho absolutos. Ex: */var/www/html/project/pagina/header.php*. Por isso o ideal é seguir a *dica 1*.

Comment: o meu header está uma pasta acima (em relação ao index.php), dentro de paginas, com: include('/paginas/header.php'); deveria ser possível incluir o header, porém não acontece...

Comment: Se você está utilizando o `index.php` que está na mesma pasta que o arquivo `package.json`, então seu include deverá ser `include('paginas/header.php');`. Editei minha resposta. Adicione uma dica.

Comment: então, estou no windows aqui e tá da forma que vc colocou aí, porém o erro persiste

Comment: Warning: include(paginas/header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\1998\relatorios_financeiros_98.php on line 2

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'paginas/header.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\1998\relatorios_financeiros_98.php on line 2

Notice: Undefined variable: _SESSION in C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\1998\relatorios_financeiros_98.php on line 4

Comment: Coloca no arquivo index.php o seguinte trecho (no topo). `die( __DIR__ );` e verifica a página. Depois é só seguir essa pasta como base.

Comment: no topo é no head?

Comment: Se possível na primeira linha do index.php. `<?php die( __DIR__ ); ?>`

Comment: C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA -- foi isso que apareceu, para chegar até o header deveria entrar somente em "paginas"... não sei o que está errado

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71548/discussion-between-valdeir-psr-and-v-avancini).