# Include em arquivo com include

Tags: php

Possuo um arquivo que faz um include de um arquivo, que está em uma pasta diferente, que por sua vez faz outro include de outro arquivo que também está em uma pasta diferente.

Este é o include:

```
include( "../header.php" );
```

[image]

Um arquivo que está dentro da pasta *"1998"* realiza include do *header.php* que está na pasta pai e o *header.php* faz include de *conexão.php, modal.php* e *pagina_verificar.php* que estão na pasta *"acoes"*, mas os seguintes erros são emitidos:

> Warning: include_once(../acoes/conexao.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../acoes/conexao.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 5
>
> Warning: include_once(../acoes/modal.php): failed to open stream: No
>   such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 6
>
> Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '../acoes/modal.php' for
>   inclusion (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 6
>
> Warning: require(../acoes/pagina_verificar.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 11
>
> Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required
>   '../acoes/pagina_verificar.php' (include_path='C:\Xampp\php\PEAR') in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PMI-WEB-CONTAB-ALPHA\paginas\header.php on line 11

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Include em pasta anterior](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/268537/include-em-pasta-anterior)

Comment: não resolvi o problema, resolvi fazer uma abordagem diferente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todos os **includes** chamados devem possuir o mesmo caminho relativo do arquivo pai.

Se vc fez `include "../header.php"`, todos os includes dentro de header.php devem ser `include "../../acoes/arquivo.php"`

Assim no seu código quando você usa `include "../acoes/pagina_verificar.php"` você esta tentando acessar **paginas/acoes/pagina_verificar.php** em vez de **acoes/pagina_verificar.php**

Comment: fiz mais ou menos isso aí, porém coloquei o caminho completo no header.php. Só que me surgiu um novo problema, parece que o bootstrap e css não estão pegando